# PySide QTreeView Reverse Order

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

Hello I am using A QTreeView with model so that I can filter for data.  I want to append line numbers to my data, but they print in reverse order.  Right now I have dummy data like this

```
# addItem is a custom function
for i in range(0, 50):
    self.addItem(model, i, "Data1", "Data2")
```

expected output

```
0 Data1 Data2
1 Data1 Data2
.
.
.
50 Data1 Data2
```

Real Output

```
50 Data1 Data2
49 Data1 Data2
.
.
.
0 Data1 Data2
```

How do I get the numbers to print correctly?

Comment: It is impossible to evaluate without knowing what addItem is doing. Add a SSCCE otherwise this questionis not particularly well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `for i in reversed(range(0, 50)):`